# Concrete table legs

Tags: concrete, engineering

the wife wants me to build a concrete table that is 10' long by 2.5' wide and 3" thick with and overall height of 30". She would like 6"x6" tubing for legs, so I was wondering how thick tubing I will need to hold up the table without the table breaking or the legs buckling? Weight of the table is roughly 940lbs.

Further notes, she wants 2' of overhang on the 2.5' sides of the table,and 7.5" of overhang on the 10' side of the table.

I was thinking that to keep the legs together I would weld some 2" flat bar across to each one that would be hidden by the concrete itself. I would then either embed anchors into the concrete and use lag bolts from the legs to attach to the table top, or embed 8" wide pieces of metal to weld the legs to once the top is in place.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Quarantine has the wife going stir crazy so she's cooking up projects for me to do.

Comment: You also need to determine whether your floor can handle that weight.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the side forces. Someday someone will try to slide the table. The feet will be stuck to the floor and there will be hundreds of pounds of side force on the legs.

Comment: The vertical load is not that much as long as it is stable with some side load. I built a 75 gallon aquarium stand, aquarium weight about 800 lbs. 4 ' long about 18" wide using 4 X 4 legs ; now 30 yr old. Also built a 135 gal into a wall , 1400+ lbs , supported by 6 wall studs 2 X 4 . It is 6 ft long.

Comment: I have made some concrete counters and I would recommend your legs be attached to the steel in the table, for that span you are going to need some angle iron to keep it from breaking in the center. I would want to weld the steel in the legs to the steel in the table.